# Is there a way to increase number of connection to AWS RDS

Tags: sql-server, typescript, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, aws-rds-data-service

I have an Excel file with 10 records. These records are getting updated into a SQL Server database using an AJAX call. This is working fine.

However, when the number of records increases to 100, I get an error

> Alert message “an error has occurred “

We are testing this feature, by keeping the database in RDS.

My question is, is there any ways to increase the number of connection in both the cases (SQL Server database in EC2 and SQL Server RDS)? Is it we can increase the number of connections then it will process more numbers of records? What is your suggestion on this? Also, how can I increase the numbers of connection in both these cases? Is there any option in database parameter group for such scenario?

Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: You need to find out more about that error - does that exception have an `.InnerException` that says a bit more about *what* unexpected error occurred?

Comment: Sorry, I just updated the exact error message. Any more clues please?

Comment: Please investigate further and find the real error message. Failing to go from 10 to 100 records has nothing to do with 'number of connections'. You probably just have dirty data

Comment: I'm investigating, The question is, what is that database parameters group feature? If somehow the Ajax call  hits the DB multiple times, does not it like the number of connections are more? And due to which I need to think about this options?

Answer (score 2):

I doubt you mentioned about `con-current connections` to **Amazon RDS instance**.

If yes, you are able to increase that number by upgrading your current *DB instance type* or modifying your *parameter group* into your requirement.

You can refer to:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Limits.html#RDS_Limits.MaxConnections

And of course, the number maybe varies based on different DB engine.

Comment: Thank you. Yes it varies based on DB. For SQL server it’s 0 default to have unlimited connection.

Comment: What do you mean by this : "I doubt you mentioned about con-current connections to Amazon RDS instance" ? Note: the calls are "Asyn" API calls.